# How to handle error when using validate() in Alamofire request?

Tags: swift, alamofire

Id like to handle status codes 100...402 and 404...599. 403 is handled by AuthInterceptor.

I have already tried to remove validate() and handle it by my own but interceptor is not called without validate() in request.

```
request = AF.request(encodedURLRequest, interceptor: AuthInterceptor()).validate().responseData { (response) in
    ...
}
```

I need to handle these status codes in that block "..."
The best way would be specifying sequence 100.599 without 403 in validate method. If is it even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retry your requests, you must produce an error at some point in Alamofire's request pipeline. `validate()` does this for you automatically, letting the request be retried before your response serializer(s) are called. You can either customize `validate()` to only care about the status codes you want, or you can create a custom response serializer and throw the error there. You could customize your validation with your own set of status codes:

```
var allowedStatusCodes = Set(200..<500)
allowedStatusCodes.remove(403)

AF.request(...).validate(statusCode: allowedStatusCodes).response { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
 Alamofire.request(urlRequest,headers:headers).validate()
        .responseJSON {
            response in

            guard response.response?.statusCode != 403 else
            {
               print("Session expired, Must relogin")
                return
            }
            guard response.response?.statusCode != 500 else
            {
                print("Something Went wrong, please refresh")
                return
            }
            guard response.response?.statusCode != 504 else
            {
               Print("Gateway timeout, Please refresh")
                return
            }
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                do{
                    let marketChart = try JSONDecoder().decode(data.self, from:response.data!)

                    completionHandler(self.array, nil)

                }
                catch {

                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
            case .failure(let error):


                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
    }
```

Comment: validate() accept only 200...299 so if I get status code like 500 its never get inside that "..." block